# Gradebook Grades acting weird

Tags: issues

We have a site that is using the gradebook. The teacher has submitted a final grade. When you view the activity, it shows the grade in the Activity Info section. However if you go to edit that record, the grade field doesn't show up. We are running CiviCRM 5.10.3. This only started after upgrading from 5.3.1. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the activity view, showing the grade
[image]

Here is the activity edit, not showing the grade.
[image]

I looked in the console while loading this in a new tab as well as the modal there wasn't any errors.

Comment: Do you mean CiviSchool?

Comment: yes can you clarify if a non-standard feature is providing 'gradebook grades' for you?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you are asking @petednz-fuzion. I don't believe that we have extensions or custom code for this.

Comment: Mike. There isn't a gradebook function in CiviCRM core so I think you must have an extension or custom code. Go to Administer > System Settings > Extensions to see if you have any installed

Comment: Oh ok. I guess I was just assuming that they were apart of the CiviCRM. The only extenstions that we have installed are:
iATS Payments
INNODB triggers
API v4
CiviDiscount

I guess I will look any custom code.

Answer (score 1):

If you go look in your Custom Fields you should find a Group set called eg Gradebooks and the fields you are describing
- Grade
- Class Grade Average
should be in that set.

If you click on either of those you may see that the field is set to be "View Only" ie "Is this field set by PHP code (via a custom hook). This field will not be updated by CiviCRM."

[image]

which would be one reason that you can't edit it.

What would be helpful is if in your question you explain the process by which the original data is added.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit of extra information that may help us:

Firstly, when you say "doesn't show up" - that's not very clear. Ideally please paste a screenshot (with names & email addresses redacted).

Secondly, please open "Console" in Google Chrome (or Developer Tools in other browsers) and see whether there are any errors.

Next (if you're on Drupal), please look in your Drupal watchdog for any errors.

Finally, if you have server access, please look in your Apache / Nginx logs and   in your ConfigAndLog CiviCRM error files.

Thanks!